# ¿Cómo evitar que los datos se descarguen cada vez que ingreso a la aplicación?

Tags: android, android-studio, json, base-de-datos

me encuentro ya finalizando el desarrollo de una aplicación Android y me encontré con dos problemas.

**P1:** los datos los descargo cuando aparece el splashscreen y almaceno en una `BD`, por ende, la próxima vez que se ingrese, no deberían de descargarse otra vez. (para esto ya había pensado usar muchos `if` o un `switch`, pero no me parece la mejor solución. `isFirstTimeLaunch()` ya lo estoy usando al momento de usar la pantalla de bienvenida por primera vez, pero podría ser una solución).

EJ:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.DATE);

if (timeOfDay == 18) {
   loadURL();
   loadURL2();
   loadURL3();
}
```

P2: los datos el algún momento deberán ser actualizados, y si se descargan solo una vez, ¿cómo los actualizo luego? (había pensado en un archivo `JSON` para esto, pero no sé cómo).

Comment: Podría haber diferentes soluciones, para ello necesitaría saber dos cosas. De donde descargas los datos la primera vez? Es un programa tuyo?

Comment: Me olvidé de aclarar, los JSON están almacenados en sites.google.com (una forma que tengo de almacenarlos). La aplicación que estoy haciendo es mía.

Comment: Tendrías alguna forma de mirar si un campo que está en descargado o no o si hay alguna actualización? Podrías servirte para los casos que has planteado.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas descargando una base de datos y no deseas descargarla nuevamente si no hasta que los datos hayan cambiado, puedes definir la fecha o un indicador en el archivo donde defines también la url para descargar la DB:

```
{  
   "date_db":"12022019",
   "db":"https://kokotito.com/database/dbfile.db"
}
```

de esta forma, si el valor de `date_db` es diferente, indicaría que tienes una nueva versión de la base de datos.

Comment: Me gusta su idea, pero no descargo una base de datos, descargo archivos JSON y los almaceno en una base de datos en el dispositivo.